# How do i stop a while loop and go to my other statements?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I want to make a program that tracks the number of CDs sold. And i want to know which is the best seller. The CD's are categorized as Alternative music classical, country, dance, pop, rock and R&B

I made a menu driven program that will display the music genres but
here's my problem: I don't know how can the user could continue on inputting the number of the genres of music sold until he wants to stop it. And after he stops how can he report on how many CDs were sold for each genre? Basically the user will continue on counting the number of CD's sold until he wants to stop the sales.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int counter = 1;
    int result, Alternative = 0, Classical = 0, Country = 0, Dance = 0, Pop = 0, Rock = 0, RnB = 0;
    cout << "Choose the music genre sold (Only choose the numbers): \n1. Alternative\n";
    cout << "2. Classical\n3. Country\n4. Dance\n5. Pop\n6. Rock\n7. R&B\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t";
    while (counter <= 100)
    {
        cin>>result;
        if(result == 1)
        {
            Alternative = Alternative + 1;
        }
        else if(result == 2)
        {
            Classical = Classical + 1;
            counter++;
        }
        else if(result == 3)
        {
            Country = Country + 1;
            counter++;
        }
        else if(result == 4)
        {
            Dance = Dance + 1;
            counter++;
        }
        else if(result == 5)
        {
            Pop = Pop + 1;
            counter++;
        }
        else if (result == 6)
        {
            Rock = Rock + 1;
            counter++;
        }
        else if (result == 7)
        {
            RnB = RnB + 1;
            counter++;
        }


        cout<<"\nAlternative:"<<Alternative;
        cout<<"\tClassical:"<<Classical;
        cout<<"\tCountry: "<<Country<<"\n";
        cout<<"Dance: "<<Dance;
        cout<<"\tPop: "<<Pop;
        cout<<"\tRock: "<<Rock;
        cout<<"\tR&B: "<<RnB<<"\t\t\t";
    }
}
```

Comment: And `switch` and `operator++`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT:

Thanks @timrau and @sfjac for the `break`, `switch` and `variable++` suggestions.

---

Instead of making the `while` loop stop after a fixed number (100) of iterations[1], you could ask the user to enter a specific character or number when he is done.

**Consider the following code, for example:**

```
// assume you have already declared and initialized all the required variables, as in your example.

// for now we will say that this is -1, so that it doesn't count as a valid option, and so it passes our while's condition.
int result = -1;

while (result)  // condition evaluates to FALSE if user enters zero.
{
    // print out the menu.
    cout << "The menu goes here... " << endl
         << "Press 0 (zero) when you are done.";

    // get the input.
    cin >> result;

    // use switch to check against constant values. Its cleaner.
    switch (result)
    {
        case 1: Alternative++;  // For incrementing variables, use the ++ operator.
                break;

        case 2: Classical++;
                break;

        // and so on, for all your choices.
        // And then,

        default: cout << "Oops! That wasn\'t a valid choice. Try again..." << endl;
    }
}

// now the user is done, and has entered 0.
cout << "\nAlternative: " << Alternative
     << "\tClassical: " << Classical
     << "\tCountry: " << Country << "\n"
     << "Dance: " << Dance
     << "\tPop: " << Pop
     << "\tRock: " << Rock
     << "\tR&B: " << RnB << "\t\t\t";

// and yes, you can fold your cout like that, so you don't have to type "cout" every time.
```

Hope that was of some help `:-)`

[1] An `iteration` is each time a loop repeats ([Iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration) on Wikipedia).

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) but when i tried running your code, it gave me an error. It says "[Error] expected unqualified-id before 'while'" ? Though i'm still trying to revise my own code based on your suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you forget to put it all inside `main()`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690446/error-expected-unqualified-id-before-if

Answer (score 0):

So add quit option to your cout:

```
cout << "2. Classical\n3. Country\n4. Dance\n5. Pop\n6. Rock\n7. R&B\n8. quit
```

Add new condition (switch is better option here) in your while loop:

```
else if(result == 8) {
    break;
}
```

Also in your first if, you should increment choice i.e. in case of alternative. Best would be incrementing choice after you read the value just once instead of duplicating in every conditions.

And your cout that prints genre's within while loop should be post end of while loop i.e. before last brace i.e. end of main.

Answer (score 0):

Allow the user to thell you that he's finished with the input:

```
//...
cout << "...7. R&B\n999.End input \t\t\t\t\t\t\t";
do { 
   //  all your statements 
} while (result!= 999);
```

Personally, I'd start the numbering with 0 for end of input and then the rest of the possible choices.  The user could quickly see how to stop and then you could write `while (result)`.  But that's matter of taste.

**Some other suggestions:**

Consider `switch` instead of your long `if...else ...` chain.  Or better here, consider using an array to avoid repetitive code:

```
   int genre[8]={};  // create ainitalised array 
    //...  as above 
    do { 
        cin>>result;
        if (result>=0 && result<8) {
           genre[result]++;
           counter++; 
           } 
        else if (result!=999)
           cout <<"Wrong value entered!\n";
      } while (result!= 999);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (counter <= 100 || result == -1)
{...}
```

you can prompt the user to type -1, if they're finished.

Or else, you may use a switch, for example:

```
bool stop = false;
while (counter <= 100 || stop)
{
  switch(result)
  {
     case 1: ...;
     case 2: ...;
     .
     .
     .
     default:
       stop = true;
  }
}
```

if the user enters a value other than [1, 7], it will exit the loop.